# Dealing with namespaces and variables in XSLT

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, namespaces

I have an xml file like the below. For brevity I am not listing it complete.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<OBJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns="http://www.example.com/"
         xsi:schemaLocation=".\\intermediate\\example.xsd">
   <OBJECT>
      <abbreviation>ABCD</abbreviation>
      <LINKS>
      ....
```

And I want to refer some parts of it in my XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:t="http://www.example.com/" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation=".\\intermediate\\example.xsd">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="objs" select ="t:OBJECTS/OBJECT"/>
<xsl:variable name="cnt" select="count($objs)"/> 

<xsl:template match="t:*">
Count of objects is <xsl:value-of select="$cnt" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My intention is to display count of all objects as per that namespace. I could not achieve this.

```
Count of objects is 100.
```

If I remove namespace in the XML file, I am getting it. Where would be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you want to achieve but I've noticed you're not using the `t:` prefix in your child selector, so I'm suggesting to use

```
<xsl:variable name="objs" select ="t:OBJECTS/t:OBJECT"/>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:variable name="objs" select ="t:OBJECTS/OBJECT"/>
```

Comment: That is correct. A default namespace (without a prefix) is inherited, so `OBJECT` is in the same namespace as its parent `OBJECTS`.

Comment: It worked perfectly. My aim is to process multiple xml documents from multiple namespaces using a single xslt. I was successful partially so far and thanks a million for giving the precise pointer in very short time.